# Custom Plugin auto update from git hub not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, github, plugins, customization

I have created a custom plugin and I have the plugin code in GITHUB , I created a php file to update the plugin automatically when a new release is added in GitHub

I am adding the code I used for updating the pluign

update.php

```
<?php

class toolkit_Updater {

    private $file;

    private $plugin;

    private $basename;

    private $active;

    private $username;

    private $repository;

    private $authorize_token;

    private $github_response;

    public function __construct( $file ) {

        $this->file = $file;

        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'set_plugin_properties' ) );

        return $this;
    }

    public function set_plugin_properties() {
        $this->plugin   = get_plugin_data( $this->file );
        $this->basename = plugin_basename( $this->file );
        $this->active   = is_plugin_active( $this->basename );
    }

    public function set_username( $username ) {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function set_repository( $repository ) {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function authorize( $token ) {
        $this->authorize_token = $token;
    }

    private function get_repository_info() {
        if ( is_null( $this->github_response ) ) { // Do we have a response?
        $args = array();
            $request_uri = sprintf( 'https://api.github.com/repos/%s/%s/releases', $this->username, $this->repository ); // Build URI
            
        $args = array();

            if( $this->authorize_token ) { // Is there an access token?
                  $args['headers']['Authorization'] = "bearer {$this->authorize_token}"; // Set the headers
            }

            $response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( $request_uri, $args ) ), true ); // Get JSON and parse it

            if( is_array( $response ) ) { // If it is an array
                $response = current( $response ); // Get the first item
            }

            $this->github_response = $response; // Set it to our property
        }
    }

    public function initialize() {
        add_filter( 'pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins', array( $this, 'modify_transient' ), 10, 1 );
        add_filter( 'plugins_api', array( $this, 'plugin_popup' ), 10, 3);
        add_filter( 'upgrader_post_install', array( $this, 'after_install' ), 10, 3 );
        
        // Add Authorization Token to download_package
        add_filter( 'upgrader_pre_download',
            function() {
                add_filter( 'http_request_args', [ $this, 'download_package' ], 15, 2 );
                return false; // upgrader_pre_download filter default return value.
            }
        );
    }

    public function modify_transient( $transient ) {

        if( property_exists( $transient, 'checked') ) { // Check if transient has a checked property

            if( $checked = $transient->checked ) { // Did Wordpress check for updates?

                $this->get_repository_info(); // Get the repo info

                $out_of_date = version_compare( $this->github_response['tag_name'], $checked[ $this->basename ], 'gt' ); // Check if we're out of date

                if( $out_of_date ) {

                    $new_files = $this->github_response['zipball_url']; // Get the ZIP

                    $slug = current( explode('/', $this->basename ) ); // Create valid slug

                    $plugin = array( // setup our plugin info
                        'url' => $this->plugin["PluginURI"],
                        'slug' => $slug,
                        'package' => $new_files,
                        'new_version' => $this->github_response['tag_name']
                    );

                    $transient->response[$this->basename] = (object) $plugin; // Return it in response
                }
            }
        }

        return $transient; // Return filtered transient
    }

    public function plugin_popup( $result, $action, $args ) {

        if( ! empty( $args->slug ) ) { // If there is a slug
            
            if( $args->slug == current( explode( '/' , $this->basename ) ) ) { // And it's our slug

                $this->get_repository_info(); // Get our repo info

                // Set it to an array
                $plugin = array(
                    'name'              => $this->plugin["Name"],
                    'slug'              => $this->basename,
                    'version'           => $this->github_response['tag_name'],
                    'author'            => $this->plugin["AuthorName"],
                    'author_profile'    => $this->plugin["AuthorURI"],
                    'last_updated'      => $this->github_response['published_at'],
                    'homepage'          => $this->plugin["PluginURI"],
                    'short_description' => $this->plugin["Description"],
                    'sections'          => array(
                        'Description'   => $this->plugin["Description"],
                        'Updates'       => $this->github_response['body'],
                    ),
                    'download_link'     => $this->github_response['zipball_url']
                );

                return (object) $plugin; // Return the data
            }

        }
        return $result; // Otherwise return default
    }
    
    public function download_package( $args, $url ) {

        if ( null !== $args['filename'] ) {
            if( $this->authorize_token ) { 
                $args = array_merge( $args, array( "headers" => array( "Authorization" => "token {$this->authorize_token}" ) ) );
            }
        }
        
        remove_filter( 'http_request_args', [ $this, 'download_package' ] );

        return $args;
    }

    public function after_install( $response, $hook_extra, $result ) {
        global $wp_filesystem; // Get global FS object

        $install_directory = plugin_dir_path( $this->file ); // Our plugin directory
        $wp_filesystem->move( $result['destination'], $install_directory ); // Move files to the plugin dir
        $result['destination'] = $install_directory; // Set the destination for the rest of the stack

        if ( $this->active ) { // If it was active
            activate_plugin( $this->basename ); // Reactivate
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

The code I added in my plugin main file is : my-plugin.php

```
<?php
if( ! class_exists( 'toolkit_Updater' ) ){
    require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'update.php' );
}

$updater = new toolkit_Updater( __FILE__ );
$updater->set_username( GITHUBUSERNAME );
$updater->set_repository( GITHUBPROJECTREPO );
$updater->authorize( ACCESSTOKEN ); // Your auth code goes here for private repos
$updater->initialize();
```

after adding all this code I am not getting update option when is release a new code in GITHUB

[image]

I need like this for my custom plugin when I add a New release in GIT HUB